# Function parameter always empty why?

Tags: function, powershell

Can someone tell me, why this function call does not work and why the argument is always empty ?

```
function check([string]$input){
  Write-Host $input                             #empty line
  $count = $input.Length                        #always 0
  $test = ([ADSI]::Exists('WinNT://./'+$input)) #exception (empty string) 
  return $test
}

check 'test'
```

Trying to get the info if an user or usergroup exists..

Best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps use a `param` block for parameters.

> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj554301.aspx

**Update**: the problem seems to be fixed if you don't use `$input` as a parameter name, maybe not a bad thing to have proper variable names ;)

Also Powershell doesn't have `return` keyword, you just push the object as a statement by itself, this will be returned by function:

```powershell
function Get-ADObjectExists
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [string]
    $ObjectName
  )
  #return result by just calling the object (no return statement in powershell)
  ([ADSI]::Exists('WinNT://./'+$ObjectName)) 
}

Get-ADObjectExists -ObjectName'test'
```

Comment: I think `$input` is a system var you shouldn't use, updated sample

Comment: Perfect. changing input to something else and it worked. Thank you soooo much

Comment: Actually PowerShell **does** have a `return` keyword and in some scenarios its quite convenient to use it: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847760%28v=wps.620%29.aspx

Comment: @ManuelBatsching hah! beat me to it by a second :)

Comment: oh joy, so I was wrong on the `param` block, `return` keyword and even took me a while to figure out `$input` was an automatic variable... pretty bad... at least I learned from this too!

Answer (score 8):

`$input` is an automatic variable.

https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh847768.aspx

> **`$Input`**
>
> Contains an enumerator that enumerates all input that is passed to a function. The `$input` variable is available only to functions and script blocks (which are unnamed functions).  In the Process block of a function, the `$input` variable enumerates the object that is currently in the pipeline. When the Process block  completes, there are no objects left in the pipeline, so the `$input` variable enumerates an empty collection. If the function does not have a Process block, then in the End block, the `$input` variable enumerates the collection of all input to the function.